# Как отметить определенное слово в консоли? С++

Tags: c++, консоль

Как можно отметить цветом определенное слово в консоли?

Comment: неужели в консоли нельзя выделить слово, неважно-цветом или как-то по- другому?

Comment: В рамках языка — никак. Стандартная библиотека C++ не поддерживает управление консолью, только вывод в режиме телетайпа. Используйте системно-зависимые способы. Например, WinAPI.

Comment: @VladD Вот полное задание: "По нажатию произвольной клавиши поочередно выделяет каждое слово текста, содержит минимальное количество символов."
Неужели так усложнили лаботаторку? Мы не событий, не винАПи не учили

Comment: Это вы спросите не у нас, а у того, кто давал задание. Может, он имел в виду конкретный компилятор и конкретную нестандартную библиотеку, откуда ж нам знать?

Comment: @VladD, нет, не изучали. 
Вы случайно не знаете, как можно использовать функцию по нажатию любой клавиатурной клавиши?

Comment: И это, что характерно, тоже не поддерживается в чистом C++, а только системно-специфическими библиотеками. :-\

Comment: @VladD, нашел подобное задание под С#, видимо, изначально задание делалось не под плюсы. 
Спасибо вам!

Comment: Ага, вот в C# с управлением консолью намного лучше. Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если использовать cout:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinCon.h>

HANDLE hStdout, hStdin; 
hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

cout << "text" << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Если компилятор - Borland C++ 3.1, то помогут функции `getch`, `gotoxy` и `cprintf`. Все из conio.h.